# Отправка команд удаленным компьютерам python

Tags: python, администрирование

Идея создания программы отправки команд удаленным компьютерам(100 шт.):
Я со своего компьютера пишиу боту в телеге, он отправляет это сообщение куда-либо (файл на DropBox, GoogleDrive и тд), вторая программа опрашивает этот файл и если есть допустим строка в файле "ТВ медуза" компьютер с именем "Медуза" перезагружает программу TeamViewer.
Как мне реализовать такую идею, может есть метод проще чем использовать сторонние сервисы, т.к. у них АПИ ограничены

Comment: Если нужно, могу примеры программ, которые я делал отправить

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы ограничить его конкретной проблемой и указать достаточно подробностей, чтобы найти адекватный ответ.

Comment: Отредактировал, основная идея в том, чтобы удаленные компьютеры как то получали сигнал на определенные действия, которые будут прописаны в коде, например реализовать shutdown, запуск батников, приложений и т.д.
Не хочется заморачиваться с разворотом сервера или настройки удаленного управления, т.к. это придется все настраивать на 100 компьютерах

Comment: Вот пример того, что я сделал:
https://github.com/FruTTi1887/DropBox-with-TG-Bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы всё попробовал реализовать исключительно через АПИ самого телеграмма.

Идея в чем, мы используем один и тот же ключ `БОТА` для всех машинах. Так как мы делаем немного случайную задержку для получения ответа с `https://api.telegram.org/bot<ваш_токен>/getUpdates` то даже сотня машин без труда сможет использовать один токен.

Когда боту отправляем команду, соответственно все машины её получают, но через условие отработает только нужная машина (*нужно для каждой машины модифицировать скрипт\условие*).

Предусмотрел запоминание уже отработанных команд, что бы по кругу их не обрабатывать.

Добавил команду для очистки очереди в самом телеграмме, и на всякий случай при старте скрипта.

```
import requests
import time
import random

api_key = 'TOKEN'

# Создаем пустой список для отслеживания уже отвеченных сообщений
answered_messages = []

# Функция для отправки сообщения
def send_message(chat_id, text, reply_to_message_id=None):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{api_key}/sendMessage'
    data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_to_message_id': reply_to_message_id}
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    return response.json

def delete_message(chat_id, message_id):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{api_key}/deleteMessage'
    data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message_id': message_id}
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    return response.json()

def clear_queue(update):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{api_key}/getUpdates'
    params = {'offset': update.get('update_id')+1}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    
# Функция для получения обновлений и обработки непрочитанных сообщений
def process_updates():
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{api_key}/getUpdates'
    response = requests.get(url)
    updates = response.json().get('result', [])
    
    for update in updates:
        message = update.get('message')
        if message and message['message_id'] not in answered_messages:
            print(message.get('text'))
            if message.get('text') == "Медуза": # Для каждого компа свои условия
                
                # Компьютер с именем "Медуза" перезагружает программу TeamViewer
                send_message(message['chat']['id'], 'TeamViewer перезагружен!', message['message_id'])
                #delete_message(message['chat']['id'], message['message_id'])
                
            # Добавляем идентификатор сообщения в список уже отвеченных сообщений
            answered_messages.append(message['message_id'])
            
            # Очистка очереди накопившихся сообщений
            if message.get('text') == "Очистить очередь сообщений!":
                send_message(message['chat']['id'], 'Очередь сообщений очищена!', message['message_id'])
                clear_queue(update)


# Очистка очереди перед стартом
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{api_key}/getUpdates'
response = requests.get(url)
updates = response.json().get('result', [])
if updates:
    clear_queue(updates[-1])

# Основной цикл программы
while True:
    process_updates()
    # Генерация случайного числа в диапазоне от 1 до 3
    random_delay = random.uniform(1, 3)
    time.sleep(random_delay)  # Пауза 1-3 секунда между запросами
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду экспериментировать с этой версией кода!